# '+' (plus sign) not encoded with RestTemplate using String url, but interpreted as ' ' (space)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timestamp, rfc3986

We are moving from Java 8 to Java 11, and thus, from Spring Boot 1.5.6 to 2.1.2. We noticed, that when using RestTemplate, the '+' sign is not encoded to '%2B' anymore (changes by SPR-14828). This would be okay, because RFC3986 doesn't list '+' as a reserved character, but it is still interpreted as a ' ' (space) when received in a Spring Boot endpoint.

We have a search query which can take optional timestamps as query parameters. The query looks something like `http://example.com/search?beforeTimestamp=2019-01-21T14:56:50%2B00:00`.

We can't figure out how to send an encoded plus sign, without it being double-encoded. Query parameter `2019-01-21T14:56:50+00:00` would be interpreted as `2019-01-21T14:56:50 00:00`. If we were to encode the parameter ourselves (`2019-01-21T14:56:50%2B00:00`), then it would be received and interpreted as `2019-01-21T14:56:50%252B00:00`.

An additional constraint is, that we want to set the base url elsewhere, when setting up the restTemplate, not where the query is being executed.

Alternatively, is there a way to force '+' not to be interpreted as ' ' by the endpoint?

I have written a short example demonstrating some ways of achieving stricter encoding with their drawbacks explained as comments:

```
package com.example.clientandserver;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ClientAndServerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientAndServerApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        String beforeTimestamp = "2019-01-21T14:56:50+00:00";

        // Previously - base url and raw params (encoded automatically). 
        // This worked in the earlier version of Spring Boot
        {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
               .rootUri("http://localhost:8080").build();
            UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/search");
            if (beforeTimestamp != null) {
                b.queryParam("beforeTimestamp", beforeTimestamp);
            }
            restTemplate.getForEntity(b.toUriString(), Object.class);
            // Received: 2019-01-21T14:56:50 00:00
            //       Plus sign missing here ^
        }

        // Option 1 - no base url and encoding the param ourselves.
        {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/search");
            if (beforeTimestamp != null) {
                b.queryParam(
                    "beforeTimestamp",
                    UriUtils.encode(beforeTimestamp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                );
            }
            restTemplate.getForEntity(
                b.build(true).toUri(), Object.class
            ).getBody();
            // Received: 2019-01-21T14:56:50+00:00
        }

        // Option 2 - with templated base url, query parameter is not optional.
        {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .rootUri("http://localhost:8080")
                .uriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory())
                .build();
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("beforeTimestamp", beforeTimestamp);
            restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "/search?beforeTimestamp={beforeTimestamp}",
                Object.class,
                params);
            // Received: 2019-01-21T14:56:50+00:00
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public void search(@RequestParam String beforeTimestamp) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + beforeTimestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this was an expected change?

Comment: If leaving the `+` (plus) sign as is were expected, then a receiving Spring Boot endpoint should not attempt to decode the `+` (plus) as a ` ` (space). Unfortunately, that is not the case due to seemingly conflicting standards.

Comment: I was having the same problem but I had started with a templated URL. The success of Option 2 seems to hinge on setting the `uriTemplateHandler` as you do... but why? I'm not grasping the difference between the `DefaultUriBuilderFactor` that you use and the `DefaultUriTemplateHandler` that would otherwise be used.

Comment: @PatrickM `DefaultUriTemplateHandler` seems to be deprecated, but the docs indicate the difference might be, that "DefaultUriBuilderFactory has a different default for the parsePath property (from false to true)."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We realized the URL can be modified in an interceptor after the encoding is done. So a solution would be to use an interceptor, that encodes the plus sign in the query params.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .rootUri("http://localhost:8080")
        .interceptors(new PlusEncoderInterceptor())
        .build();
```

A shortened example:

```
public class PlusEncoderInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        return execution.execute(new HttpRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public URI getURI() {
                URI u = super.getURI();
                String strictlyEscapedQuery = StringUtils.replace(u.getRawQuery(), "+", "%2B");
                return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(u)
                        .replaceQuery(strictlyEscapedQuery)
                        .build(true).toUri();
            }
        }, body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are the needed includes:

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
    import org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpRequestWrapper;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been discussed here as well.

[Encoding of URI Variables on RestTemplate [SPR-16202]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20750)

A simpler solution is to set the encoding mode on the URI builder to VALUES_ONLY.

```
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory builderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    builderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("http://localhost:8080")
            .uriTemplateHandler(builderFactory)
            .build();
```

This achieved the same result as using the PlusEncodingInterceptor when using query parameters.

Comment: It didn't work along with `UriComponentsBuilder`, as the query parameters aren't necessarily required, but optional.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466695/gregor-eesmaa, it solved my issue. Just wanted to add that in case if you can format URL before calling `RestTemplate`, you can fix the URL at once (instead of replacing it in `PlusEncoderInterceptor`):

```java
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/search");
uriBuilder.queryParam("beforeTimestamp", "2019-01-21T14:56:50+00:00");
URI uriPlus = uriBuilder.encode().build(false).toUri();

// import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
String strictlyEscapedQuery = StringUtils.replace(uriPlus.getRawQuery(), "+", "%2B");
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uriPlus)
        .replaceQuery(strictlyEscapedQuery)
        .build(true).toUri();

// prints "/search?beforeTimestamp=2019-01-21T14:56:50%2B00:00"
System.out.println(uri);
```

Then you can use in `RestTemplate` call:

```java
RequestEntity<?> requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(uri).build();
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around this kind of issue, I found it easier to build the URI by hand.

```
URI uri = new URI(siteProperties.getBaseUrl()
  + "v3/elements/"
  + URLEncoder.encode("user/" + user + "/type/" + type, UTF_8)
  + "/"
  + URLEncoder.encode(id, UTF_8)
);

restTemplate.exchange(uri, DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), Void.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add on!, You can try with this without configure every where u used RestTemplate in your project, config also support UTF-8 encoding respons:

```
public class PlusEncoderInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException {
    return execution.execute(new HttpRequestWrapper(request) {
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public URI getURI() {
            URI u = super.getURI();
            String strictlyEscapedQuery = StringUtils.replace(u.getRawQuery(), "+", "%2B");
            return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(u).replaceQuery(strictlyEscapedQuery).build(true).toUri();
        }
    }, body);
}
}

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().interceptors(new PlusEncoderInterceptor()).build();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return restTemplate;
}
}
```